# How do I prevent JQuery.ajax from keeping all response contents in memory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $.ajax to download a large CSV, which I am processing as it downloads using `onprogress`. I'd rather not retain all of the file contents in memory so that my tool has less of a memory footprint. But I don't know how to prevent jquery from retaining the entire csv contents to pass into the `done` method.

```
$.ajax(url, {
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function (e) {
                    //load up lines from this part of the file using e.currentTarget.response
                }
            }
        })
            .done(function (res) {
                //don't need res here as processing is already done.
            })
```

Does anyone know if there is some way of achieving this using $.ajax or something equivalent?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. The underlying `XMLHttpRequest` does this, not jQuery.

Comment: With Fetch, you can probably do this through the [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) interface